# Codeigniter Fetch data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to fetch de data from my database and show it in my view.
But I don't seem to get it right. I worked a bit with codeIgniter and I know you can display your data in the view in a way that goes something like this:

```
{data}{dataname}{/data}
```

And this would show you every record of the dataname.

This is my model:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}   

public function Get_Pedras()
{
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM pedras;");
    $row = $query->row_array();
    return $row;
}
```

And this is my controller

```
public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('Pedras_Model');
            $this->load->helper('url_helper');
    }
public function index (){


    $this->load->view('Main/Formulario_Email');
}

public function GetStone(){
    $this->load->library('parser');
    $name = $this->Pedras_Model->Get_Pedras();

    $data = array(
        'title' => 'IdPedra',
        'heading' => 'NomePedra'
    );
    $this->load->view('Main/Formulario_Email', $data);
}
```

And at least my view:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1">
                                    {data}
                                    {title}
                                    {/data}
                                    </div>
```

I think I might be missing something realy important, but I only worked a little bit with CI, and some time ago, could you be helping me out pls? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please take some time to review the very comprehensive CodeIgniter Guide: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/welcome.html

Comment: @AdamMoffat, ty for the advise, Thats something I have been doing for some hours, and I dont seem to get what I'm doing wrong, any idea?

Comment: please check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49862710/unable-to-display-query-results-in-a-view-codeigniter/49863251#49863251

Comment: you also may want to look-up the CI template library here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html

Comment: Ty @Vickel, I will be looking at it!

Answer (score 0):

In your **Model** don't use `row_array` because you are querying all the available data from your table. use `result_array` instead.

Like this...

```
public function Get_Pedras(){
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM pedras;");
return $query->result_array();
```

}

Try this one in your **Controller**...

```
public function GetStone(){
$this->load->library('parser');
$data['pedras'] = $this->Pedras_Model->Get_Pedras();

$this->load->view('Main/Formulario_Email', $data); //pass data here!
```

}

then in your view, **in order to display the data** do this...

```
foreach($pedras as $p){
 echo $p['data']; //rename data with you query_name.
```

}