# How can I get the 'id' property of non-object CodeIgniter 3.1?

Tags: php, mysql, search, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

I have a problem creating the "search" feature where I get an error like this:

> Severity: Notice
> Message: Trying to get the 'id' property of non-object
> Filename: pages / search.php
> Line Number: 77
> Backtrace:
> File: G: \ Program \ xampp \ htdocs \ report \ application \ views \ pages \ search.php
> Line: 77
> Function: _error_handler
> File: G: \ Program \ xampp \ htdocs \ report \ application \ controllers \ control.php
> Line: 26
> Function: view
> File: G: \ Program \ xampp \ htdocs \ report \ index.php
> Line: 315
> Function: require_once

Homepage

```
    foreach ($laporan as $d) {
        $link = base_url('control/lihat/' . $d->id);
        echo "<p>" . $d->laporan . "</p>",
        "<div class='box-h'>",
        "<div class='lampiran'>",
        "<p>Lampiran : " . $d->lampiran . "</p>",
        "</div>",
        "</div>";
    }
```

Controller

```
    public function search() 
    {
        $search = $this->input->post('search');
        $data['laporan'] =  $this->control_model->search_laporan($search);
        $this->load->view('pages/search');
    }
```

Model

```
    public function search_laporan($keyword)
    {
        $this->db->like('laporan', $keyword);
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from laporan where aspek like '%$keyword%' ");
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: When you dump `$d`, what does it contain?

Comment: just need to update this line in the controller `$this->load->view('pages/search',$data);`

Comment: @One Circle Software your problem is solved or not??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unable to display query results in a view codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49862710/unable-to-display-query-results-in-a-view-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing `laporan` from controller to view.
If you think you have data returned in `laporan` variable then your controller should look something like this.

Controller

```
public function search(){
    $search = $this->input->post('search');
    $data['laporan'] =  $this->control_model->search_laporan($search);
    $this->load->view('pages/search', $data);  #notice this line
}
```

Comment: can u remote my pc via ultraviewer please?